# CSS Show border after heading

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I want a heading like shown in the picture [image: picture].

Currently I have 3 flex columns:

```
<section id="section1" class="py-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="p-2 w-50 text-center"><h1>OUR DIVISIONS</h1></div>
            <div class="p-2 w-25 text-center"><h1>Sample Heading 2</h1></div>
            <div class="p-2 w-25 text-center">Sample Heading 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

As shown in the picture, I need the OUR____ line effect in the heading.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the question/issue?

Comment: it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Do you want 3 headlines? Or do you want the "our________" line effect?

Comment: @BO41, yes i want the Our_____ line effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did for dynamic width:

```
<section id="section1" class="py-5">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="p-2 w-50">
                <h1 class="heading">
                    <span class="heading1">OUR</span>
                    <br>
                    <span class="heading2">DIVISIONS</span>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="p-2 w-25 text-center"><h1>Sample Heading 2</h1></div>
            <div class="p-2 w-25 text-center">Sample Heading 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS used:

```
.heading{
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: inline-block;
}

.heading2{
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.heading span.heading1:after{
    content:'';
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    margin-right:-100%;
    border-bottom:2px solid #000;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Hope this helps someone too...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to come up with something close to what you seem to be looking for but, in my opinion, it is highly dependent on the width of the container (i.e. h1, h2, etc)

Perhaps you can use the code provided below and adapt it to your own needs?

**See demo code below**

```css
.w-50 {
  background-color: #f8db7d;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 160px;
}

.w-50>h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.w-50>h2 {
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100px;
}

.w-50 > h1 > span {
  width: 100px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  line-height: .8em;
}
```

```html
<section id="section1" class="py-5">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex">
      <div class="p-2 w-50 text-center">        
        <h1>OUR<span/></h1>
        <h2>DIVISIONS</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="p-2 w-25 text-center">
        <h1>Sample Heading 2</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="p-2 w-25 text-center">Sample Heading 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The underline should adjust itself according to the max width of 2nd heading

Answer (score 0):

So I would try it with an `:after` element.

The best think I came up is:

```css
.underline:after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 1px black solid;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 85px;
}
```

```html
<div style="display: inline-block">
  <h1 class="underline">
    our
  </h1>
  <h1>
    Divisions
  </h1>
</div>
```

The only problem with this is, the width is set fixed to 85px. So with other headlines you need to adapt the width